# Python list type declaration

Tags: python

I tried to set variable types in my functions. There is no problem when I tried to use normal variable type. For example,

```
def myString(name:str) -> str:
    return "hello " + name
```

However, I got problem in list. Many examples in internet said use **List**, but it got error. Now I use **list**, and there is no error. Is it ok to use this?

Another problem that I found someone can use

```
def myListString() -> list[str]:
    return ["ABC", "CDE"]
```

I found error.

```
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
```

How should I correct this?

Another problem that I found is I cannot declare **myClass** in the **myClass**. For example,

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x:int, y:int):
        self.x:int = x
        self.y:int = y

    def isSamePoint(self, p:Point) -> bool:
        return ((self.x==p.x) and (self.y==p.y))
p0 = Point(10, 5)
p1 = Point(5, 5)
p0.isSamePoint(p1)
```

I found error,

```
def isSamePoint(self, p:Point):
NameError: name 'Point' is not defined
```

Please help me solve the problem.

Comment: what python version are you using?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable

Python 3.9 allows for `list[str]`. Earlier you had to import [`List`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/typing.html?highlight=list#typing.List) from `typing` and do `-> List[str]`.

> NameError: name 'Point' is not defined

If you want to declare the type of "self" you can either put that in a string `def isSamePoint(self, p: "Point") -> bool:` or create an interface.

```
>>> class A: pass
>>> class B(A): pass
>>> b = B()
>>> isinstance(b, A)
True
```

so `def isSamePoint(self, p: A)` would do the trick.

Also, if you want to check if `isSamePoint` you might want to consider your own `__eq__`.

Answer (score 0):

To declare the type hint of 'self' for Python 3.7, you need to import:

```
  from future__ import annotations
```

at the beginning of the file. That's all you need to do.
From now you can use same class type hint:

```
def isSamePoint (self, p: Point) -> bool:
```

instead of class name as a string:

```
def isSamePoint (self, p: 'Point') -> bool:
```